# Display font-awesome icon on top of another image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I am getting image source from **json** & displaying in html page....

[image]

on top of the image , I want to add **font-awesome** icon as below ....

[image]

[image]

So i tried below code , but font-awesome icon not displaying....

**html**

```
<link 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' >
```

**script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var maskedImageUrla = "";
            var fontawesome = "<i class='fa fa-user-plus fa-2x'></i>";

            $.getJSON('test.json', function(json) {

              if (tl.src)
               {
                 maskedImageUrla = 'http://sitename.com/images/' + tl.src;
               }

                        var mask1 = $(".container").mask({
                            maskImageUrl: maskedImageUrla,
                            fontawesome: fontawesome,
                            onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {}
                        });
}); // end of document ready
```

Here is [json file](https://pastebin.com/QsvjPLx8)

Here is https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/bZNNXJ

**Update** : I added code Snippet below....

```js
var mask1;
 
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var maskedImageUrla = "";
    var fontawesome = "<i class='fa fa-user-plus fa-2x'></i>";
    var coordinates = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    };
 
    var width = 0; var height = 0;
 
   var json = {
  "path" : " love shape\/",
  "info" : {
    "author" : "",
    "keywords" : "",
    "file" : "love shape",
    "date" : "sRGB",
    "title" : "",
    "description" : "Normal",
    "generator" : "Export Kit v1.2.8"
  },
  "name" : "love shape",
  "layers" : [
    {
      "x" : 0,
      "height" : 612,
      "layers" : [
        {
          "x" : 0,
          "color" : "0xFFFFFF",
          "height" : 612,
          "y" : 0,
          "width" : 612,
          "shapeType" : "rectangle",
          "type" : "shape",
          "name" : "bg_rectangle_1"
        },
        {
          "x" : 49,
          "height" : 480,
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 0,
              "height" : 480,
              "src" : "hQ45RtK.png",
              "y" : 0,
              "width" : 514,
              "type" : "image",
              "name" : "mask_image_1"
            },
            {
              "radius" : "27 \/ 27",
              "color" : "0xACACAC",
              "x" : 233,
              "y" : 205,
              "height" : 53,
              "width" : 53,
              "shapeType" : "ellipse",
              "type" : "shape",
              "name" : "useradd_ellipse1"
            }
          ],
          "y" : 66,
          "width" : 514,
          "type" : "group",
          "name" : "user_image_1"
        }
      ],
      "y" : 0,
      "width" : 612,
      "type" : "group",
      "name" : "loveshape_18"
    }
  ]
};
   
   
   
        for (let layer of json.layers)
        {
            width = layer.width;
            height = layer.height;
            if (layer.layers && layer.layers.length > 0)
            {
               for (let temp of layer.layers)
                {
 
                   if (temp.src) maskedImageUrla = temp.src;
                    else if (temp.layers)
                    {
                        for (let tl of temp.layers)
                            if (tl.src)
                            {
                                maskedImageUrla = 'https://i.imgur.com/' + tl.src;
                                coordinates.x = temp.x;
                                coordinates.y = temp.y;
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
 
        $(".container").css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');
 
        var mask1 = $(".container").mask({
            maskImageUrl: maskedImageUrla,
            fontawesome : fontawesome,
            onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {
 
                img.css({
                    "position": "fixed",
                    "left": coordinates.x + "px",
                    "top": coordinates.y + "px"
                });
            }
        });
 
        fileupa1.onchange = function() {
            mask1.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileupa1.files[0]));
        };
    
 
}); // end of document ready
 
// jq plugin for mask
(function($) {
    var JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position
            y: 0, // image start position
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
        }, options);
 
 
        var container = $(this);
 
        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            div;
 
        container.mousePosition = function(event) {
            return {
                x: event.pageX || event.offsetX,
                y: event.pageY || event.offsetY
            };
        }
 
        container.selected = function(ev) {
            var pos = container.mousePosition(ev);
            var item = $(".masked-img canvas").filter(function() {
                var offset = $(this).offset()
                var x = pos.x - offset.left;
                var y = pos.y - offset.top;
                var d = this.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
                return d[0] > 0
            });
 
            JQmasks.forEach(function(el) {
                var id = item.length > 0 ? $(item).attr("id") : "";
                if (el.id == id)
                    el.item.enable();
                else el.item.disable();
            });
        };
 
        container.enable = function() {
            draggable = true;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 2
            });
        }
 
        container.disable = function() {
            draggable = false;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "false");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 1
            });
        }
 
        container.onDragStart = function(evt) {
            container.selected(evt);
            prevX = evt.clientX;
            prevY = evt.clientY;
        };
 
        container.getImagePosition = function() {
            return {
                x: settings.x,
                y: settings.y,
                scale: settings.scale
            };
        };
 
        container.onDragOver = function(evt) {
            if (draggable && $(canvas).attr("active") === "true") {
               var x = settings.x + evt.clientX - prevX;
                var y = settings.y + evt.clientY - prevY;
                if (x == settings.x && y == settings.y)
                   return; // position has not changed
                settings.x += evt.clientX - prevX;
                settings.y += evt.clientY - prevY;
                prevX = evt.clientX;
                prevY = evt.clientY;
                container.updateStyle();
            }
        };
 
        container.updateStyle = function() {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                context.beginPath();
                context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
                image = new Image();
                image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                image.src = settings.maskImageUrl;
                image.onload = function() {
                    canvas.width = image.width;
                    canvas.height = image.height;
                    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
                    div.css({
                        "width": image.width,
                        "height": image.height
                    });
                };
 
                img = new Image();
                img.src = settings.imageUrl;
                img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                img.onload = function() {
                    settings.x = settings.x == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.x;
                    settings.y = settings.y == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.y;
                    context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
                    context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, img.width * settings.scale, img.height * settings.scale);
                    initImage = false;
                };
            }, 0);
        };
 
        // change the draggable image
        container.loadImage = function(imageUrl) {
            if (img)
                img.remove();
            // reset the code.
            settings.y = startY;
            settings.x = startX;
            prevX = prevY = 0;
            settings.imageUrl = imageUrl;
            initImage = true;
            container.updateStyle();
        };
 
        // change the masked Image
        container.loadMaskImage = function(imageUrl, from) {
            if (div)
                div.remove();
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", settings.id);
            settings.maskImageUrl = imageUrl;
            div = $("<div/>", {
                "class": "masked-img"
            }).append(canvas);
 
            div.find("canvas").on('touchstart mousedown', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.onDragStart(event);
            });
 
            div.find("canvas").on('touchend mouseup', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.selected(event);
            });
 
            div.find("canvas").bind("dragover", container.onDragOver);
            container.append(div);
            if (settings.onMaskImageCreate)
                settings.onMaskImageCreate(div);
            container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl);
        };
        container.loadMaskImage(settings.maskImageUrl);
        JQmasks.push({
            item: container,
            id: settings.id
        })
        return container;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.temp
{
border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
display: flex;
background :silver;
}
 
.container canvas {
    display: block;
}
 
.masked-img {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 50px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<link
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' >
 
 
image 1
<input id="fileupa1"  type="file">
 
<div class="container">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope This is the result you are looking for

```js
var mask1;
 
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var maskedImageUrla = "";
    var fontawesome = "<i class='fa fa-user-plus fa-2x'></i>";
    var coordinates = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    };
 
    var width = 0; var height = 0;
 
   var json = {
  "path" : " love shape\/",
  "info" : {
    "author" : "",
    "keywords" : "",
    "file" : "love shape",
    "date" : "sRGB",
    "title" : "",
    "description" : "Normal",
    "generator" : "Export Kit v1.2.8"
  },
  "name" : "love shape",
  "layers" : [
    {
      "x" : 0,
      "height" : 612,
      "layers" : [
        {
          "x" : 0,
          "color" : "0xFFFFFF",
          "height" : 612,
          "y" : 0,
          "width" : 612,
          "shapeType" : "rectangle",
          "type" : "shape",
          "name" : "bg_rectangle_1"
        },
        {
          "x" : 49,
          "height" : 480,
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 0,
              "height" : 480,
              "src" : "hQ45RtK.png",
              "y" : 0,
              "width" : 514,
              "type" : "image",
              "name" : "mask_image_1"
            },
            {
              "radius" : "27 \/ 27",
              "color" : "0xACACAC",
              "x" : 233,
              "y" : 205,
              "height" : 53,
              "width" : 53,
              "shapeType" : "ellipse",
              "type" : "shape",
              "name" : "useradd_ellipse1"
            }
          ],
          "y" : 66,
          "width" : 514,
          "type" : "group",
          "name" : "user_image_1"
        }
      ],
      "y" : 0,
      "width" : 612,
      "type" : "group",
      "name" : "loveshape_18"
    }
  ]
};
   
   
   
        for (let layer of json.layers)
        {
            width = layer.width;
            height = layer.height;
            if (layer.layers && layer.layers.length > 0)
            {
               for (let temp of layer.layers)
                {
 
                   if (temp.src) maskedImageUrla = temp.src;
                    else if (temp.layers)
                    {
                        for (let tl of temp.layers)
                            if (tl.src)
                            {
                                maskedImageUrla = 'https://i.imgur.com/' + tl.src;
                                coordinates.x = temp.x;
                                coordinates.y = temp.y;
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
 
        $(".container").css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');
 
        var mask1 = $(".container").mask({
            maskImageUrl: maskedImageUrla,
            fontawesome : fontawesome,
            onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {
 
                img.css({
                    "position": "fixed",
                    "left": coordinates.x + "px",
                    "top": coordinates.y + "px"
                });
            }
        });
 
        fileupa1.onchange = function() {
            mask1.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileupa1.files[0]));
        };
    
 
}); // end of document ready
 
// jq plugin for mask
(function($) {
    var JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position
            y: 0, // image start position
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
        }, options);
 
 
        var container = $(this);
 
        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            div;
 
        container.mousePosition = function(event) {
            return {
                x: event.pageX || event.offsetX,
                y: event.pageY || event.offsetY
            };
        }
 
        container.selected = function(ev) {
            var pos = container.mousePosition(ev);
            var item = $(".masked-img canvas").filter(function() {
                var offset = $(this).offset()
                var x = pos.x - offset.left;
                var y = pos.y - offset.top;
                var d = this.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
                return d[0] > 0
            });
 
            JQmasks.forEach(function(el) {
                var id = item.length > 0 ? $(item).attr("id") : "";
                if (el.id == id)
                    el.item.enable();
                else el.item.disable();
            });
        };
 
        container.enable = function() {
            draggable = true;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 2
            });
        }
 
        container.disable = function() {
            draggable = false;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "false");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 1
            });
        }
 
        container.onDragStart = function(evt) {
            container.selected(evt);
            prevX = evt.clientX;
            prevY = evt.clientY;
        };
 
        container.getImagePosition = function() {
            return {
                x: settings.x,
                y: settings.y,
                scale: settings.scale
            };
        };
 
        container.onDragOver = function(evt) {
            if (draggable && $(canvas).attr("active") === "true") {
               var x = settings.x + evt.clientX - prevX;
                var y = settings.y + evt.clientY - prevY;
                if (x == settings.x && y == settings.y)
                   return; // position has not changed
                settings.x += evt.clientX - prevX;
                settings.y += evt.clientY - prevY;
                prevX = evt.clientX;
                prevY = evt.clientY;
                container.updateStyle();
            }
        };
 
        container.updateStyle = function() {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                context.beginPath();
                context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
                image = new Image();
                image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                image.src = settings.maskImageUrl;
                image.onload = function() {
                    canvas.width = image.width;
                    canvas.height = image.height;
                    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
                    div.css({
                        "width": image.width,
                        "height": image.height
                    });
                };
 
                img = new Image();
                img.src = settings.imageUrl;
                img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                img.onload = function() {
                    settings.x = settings.x == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.x;
                    settings.y = settings.y == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.y;
                    context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
                    context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, img.width * settings.scale, img.height * settings.scale);
                    initImage = false;
                };
            }, 0);
        };
 
        // change the draggable image
        container.loadImage = function(imageUrl) {
            if (img)
                img.remove();
            // reset the code.
            settings.y = startY;
            settings.x = startX;
            prevX = prevY = 0;
            settings.imageUrl = imageUrl;
            initImage = true;
            container.updateStyle();
        };
 
        // change the masked Image
        container.loadMaskImage = function(imageUrl, from) {
            if (div)
                div.remove();
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", settings.id);
            settings.maskImageUrl = imageUrl;
            div = $("<div/>", {
                "class": "masked-img"
            }).append(canvas);
 
            div.find("canvas").on('touchstart mousedown', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.onDragStart(event);
            });
 
            div.find("canvas").on('touchend mouseup', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.selected(event);
            });
 
            div.find("canvas").bind("dragover", container.onDragOver);
            container.append(div);
            if (settings.onMaskImageCreate)
                settings.onMaskImageCreate(div);
            container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl);
        };
        container.loadMaskImage(settings.maskImageUrl);
        JQmasks.push({
            item: container,
            id: settings.id
        })
        return container;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.temp
{
border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
display: flex;
background :silver;
}
 .container 
 {
 position : relative
 }
 .container i
 {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 bottom:0;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 margin:auto;
 height:20px;
 width:20px;
 z-index:999;
 }
.container canvas {
    display: block;
}
 
.masked-img {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 50px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
 
image 1
<input id="fileupa1"  type="file">
 
<div class="container">


<i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i>

</div>
```